# Javascript countdown to never show 0 minutes

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm working on a countdown timer for a site - it doesn't actually have a purpose, it's just there. So basically at midnight it starts at 24 hours, counts down the entire day, resets at midnight again. I have the timer working, the only problem is that I want to make sure it never says "0 HRS, 0 MIN" - It should stay on 1 MIN until it resets. I thought I found a way, but I'm not sure it's working:

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
var hours = {start: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day), end: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day)};


updateCountDown();
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval('updateCountDown()', 1000);
});

function updateCountDown(){
    var date = new Date();
    var hourDiff = 23 - date.getHours();
    var minDiff = 59 - date.getMinutes();


    $('span.hours').html(23-date.getHours());
    $('span.minutes').html(59 - date.getMinutes());

    if (hourDiff == 0 && minDiff == 0 ) {
     minDiff = 1;
    };
};
```

Is there a way to test this without waiting until midnight tonight to see what happens? I tried changing the new Date() inside the updateCountDown to new Date('2/5/13 4:30:00') but it didn't work.

Comment: can't you just subtract the current time from the next midnight and show that?

Comment: Never use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a string argument!!!

Comment: What are those `hourDiff` and `minDiff` variables good for? You never use them for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was updating the `minDiff` variable after showing it.

Try this:

```
var date = new Date();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
var hours = {start: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day), end: new Date(date.getFullYear(), month, day)};


updateCountDown();
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(updateCountDown, 1000);
 });

function updateCountDown(){
    var date = new Date();
    var hourDiff = 23 - date.getHours();
    var minDiff = 59 - date.getMinutes();

    if (hourDiff == 0 && minDiff == 0 ) {
      minDiff = 1;
    };

    $('span.hours').html(hourDiff);
    $('span.minutes').html(minDiff);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To test, just replace your call to `new Date()` in your `updateCountDown` method with `new Date(2013, 01, 01, 23, 59, 50)`.

And use the code posted by Marcus.

Comment: Yes, that will also work, but it doesn't give you much testing time!

Comment: When I do that, it shows 21 Hrs and 59 Min to go, and doesn't seem to actually be counting down. I ran into the same issue when I tried to change the date before, it never actually counted down.

Comment: The code that Marcus provided is working perfectly, and I was able to test it by altering the clock on the computer, but I am curious about why it doesn't count down with a set date, if anyone has any thoughts.

Comment: Oops!  I originally didn't have a month/day in there.  Now it's Jan 1, 2013, 23:59:00.  It won't count down if you always have the set date, because each time the function is called, you're setting the same date.